# Defining extra packages in pyproject.toml for poetry

Tags: python, python-packaging, python-poetry

I am new to poetry and have a question regarding pyproject.toml.

##### Problem Statement

Suppose there is a package called "main" that has some additional extra packages e.g main[extra1], main[extra2], etc. I want to seperate these extra packages in pyproject.toml to allow the users some flexibility. How do I go define this in the pyproject.toml ?

##### My Solution

After reading the poetry documentation, I came upon the concept of dependencies group which I found very interesting and I used that in the PoC. I have structured my pyproject.toml in the following way:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]

# general dependencies
python = "3.10.8"
main = "{version_number}"


[tool.poetry.group.extra1.dependencies]
main[extra1] = "{version_number}"
```

##### Error

But when I tried to use either `poetry install --with extra1` or `poetry update --with extra1`, I encountered the following error:

```
Expected '=' after a key in a key/value pair (at line 46, column 13)
```

Comment: What is line at 46 and column 13? What is `main`? The notation `main[extra1]` seems clearly incorrect. -- If you want users of your project to be able to install `extra1` then `extra1` should be an [extra](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#extras) and not an optional development dependency group, because those are for development only.

Comment: Are you asking how to "forward" extras? That is, define extras for _your_ distribution that enable certain extras for a _different_ distribution?

Comment: *main* is just an arbitrary name. Yes, I think "forwarding" extras is what I am looking for. For example, let's say I create a custom Python package that is called "example" and it depends on "pandas". At the same time, I defined an extra in my distribution, and let's call this "extra1" that depends on scikit-learn. If I use pip:

1. pip install example -> This will install my distribution and pandas
2.pip install example[extra1] -> This will install my distribution, pandas, and scikit-learn.

How can I structure pyproject.toml to allow this?

Comment: @aweeb I think you're describing ordinary extras. If you just need `example` to provide extras (and not, say, a second package `example-user` that provides _its own_ extras that control `examples` extras), you follow [this example example in the poetry docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#extras). For the example in your comment, just add `scikit-learn` to the main dependencies with `optional = true`, and add an entry to `[tool.poetry.extras]` like `extra1 = ["scikit-learn"]`